# Confusion regarding while loop in for loop for time complexity

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, time-complexity, code-complexity

I'm learning about time complexity and I understand the gist of it, but there's one thing that's really confusing me, it's about understanding the time complexity of a while loop in a for loop.

This is the code I am analyzing:

```
    sum := 0
    for i := 1 to n
       j := 1
       while j ≤ i
          sum += j
          j*=5
       end
    end
```

I've given a shot at this and I made this table, breaking it down:

| CODE: | COST: | # OF TIMES: | TIME COMPLEXITY: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `sum := 0` | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| `for i := 1 to n` | int i = 1 (1) | 1 | 2n+1 |
|  | i<=n (1) | n+1 |  |
|  | i++ (1) | n |  |
| `j := 1` | 1 | n | n |
| `while j ≤ i` | j ≤ i (1) | ? | ? |
| `sum += j` | 1 | ? | ? |
| `j*=5` | 1 | ? | ? |
| `end` | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| `end` | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I understand the how the time complexity works for the for loop, but when I get to the while loop I'm confused.

I know that assignments have cost of 1 and comparisons have a cost of 1.

If the while loop was written as:

```
    sum:=0
    j:=1
    while j<=n
       sum+=j
       j*=5
    end
```

Since it's moving in increments of 5: `(j*=5)`, its time complexity would be: `log base5 n`.

But the while loop in the code goes `j<=i`, which is throwing me off.

I someone could help me with cost/# of times the individual lines of the while loop, I would really appreciate it.

fyi: this isn't an assignment for school or anything like that, I'm genuinely trying to understand this concept for myself.

[If the table above doesn't format correctly, here is a ss of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcrCX.png)

Comment: Constants don't count in big-O calculations.  All you care about is the the exponent, i.e. `O(1)` (constant time), `O(n)` (linear), `O(n^x)` (polynomial), or `O(e^n)` (exponential), where `n` is the input size, `x` is some exponent (>0, note `O(1)` is just `O(n^0)`), `e` is an exponential base (usually _e_ or _10_).

Comment: Yes, I know that (I should've mentioned this), but I also want to include all the coefficients/constants while doing the calculations and add it up at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is equivalent to the sum of `log_5(i)` for all `i` from `1` to `n`. The logarithm base doesn't matter, it's a constant; so i'll just say `log` from now on. This summation is asymptotically equal to `n log n`. Think about it this way: If you look at the graph of `log`, it's *really, really* flat, so *most* of the higher values in your summation look the same to the `log` function. This is only an intuition hint, not a formal proof, but it's sufficient. If you need a formal proof, [check out this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228744/value-of-summation-of-logn)